# Australia visa Immigrant country-of-origin preferences?

Tags: working-visas, australia

Just a general question for those lucky enough to hold dual-triple-etc citizenships. Does Australia Immigration have preferences/bias to the number of skilled independent worker visa's (subclass 189) given out to different countries? (e.g. is it better to apply with an EU – European Union, Germany or UK for example – citizenship, a USA citizenship, or Canadian citizenship?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**.  All preferences accorded to country of origin, citizenship, race, ethnicity etc were [abolished in 1973](https://www.immi.gov.au/media/fact-sheets/08abolition.htm), along with the last remnants of the White Australia policy:

> In 1973 the Whitlam Labor government took three further steps in the
>   gradual process to remove race as a factor in Australia's immigration
>   policies.
>
> These were to:
>
> - legislate that all migrants, of whatever origin, be eligible to obtain citizenship after three years of permanent residence
> - issue policy instructions to overseas posts to totally disregard race as a factor in the selection of migrants
> - ratify all international agreements relating to immigration and race.

And while there are [overall caps and quotas](https://www.immi.gov.au/media/fact-sheets/21managing.htm) on certain types of visas granted per year, as far as I'm aware there are none on visas per country.

Note that there are some temporary visas (eg. [working holiday](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/417.aspx)) that are restricted to nationals of some countries, but this is mostly a quid-pro-quo thing, and none of these are an official path to getting residence in Australia.

Comment: This does answer my question, I have looked into the quota's for each type of visas, and the breakdown per job type applicant (which is what brought me to ask this question to maybe have an edge). I guess I'll just have to start the process and see what happens. Thanks for the response :)